# About inverse matrix in portfolio choice

Tags: matrices

I am reading a finance book (Pennacchi's Theory of Asset Pricing p.247).
In the section on the continuous-time dynamic programming, the author
derived one first-order condition:

\begin{equation}
\left(\mu_{i}-r\right)W\frac{\partial J}{\partial W}+\frac{1}{2}W^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial W^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_{ij}\omega_{j}^{*}+W\sum_{j=1}^{n}\phi_{ij}\frac{\partial^{2}J}{\partial W\partial x_{j}}=0\quad (*)
\end{equation}
 where $\omega_{j},\mu_{i},r,W,x_{j}$ and $\phi_{ij}$ are all scalars.
Meanwhile, $J$ is defined as $J(W,x,t)$ where $x$ is a vector $x_{i}$,
$i=1,\ldots,k$. Moreover, $\omega_{j}^{*}$ is the optimal portfolio
weight assigned to asset $j$. In total, we have $n$ assets. The
finance backgroud here does not matter much. I just want to understand
how the author takes the inverse. Let $\Omega\equiv[\sigma_{ij}]_{n\times n}$
be the covariance matrix. Let $\Omega^{-1}\equiv[v_{ij}]$. From ($*$),
he directly gives 
\begin{equation}
\omega_{i}^{*}=-\frac{J_{W}}{J_{WW}W}\sum_{j=1}^{n}v_{ij}(\mu_{j}-r)-\sum_{m=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{J_{Wx_{m}}}{J_{WW}W}\phi_{jm}v_{ij},\ i=1,\ldots,n,\quad(**)
\end{equation}
 where he uses subscript to indicate the partial derivative. For example,
$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W}=J_{W}$. My questions are as follows.
(1) How do we write ($*$) in the matrix form? (2) How do
we take the inverse and get (**)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\omega,\mu$ as $n$ dimensional vectors and $\Sigma$ - covariance matrix,
$\Phi$ is also a matrix. 
Then the matrix form of $(*)$ will be 
$$
(\mu-r)W J_W +1/2 W^2 J_{WW}\Sigma \omega +W \Phi \frac{\delta J_w}{\delta x}=0
$$
Mulitply everything by inverse $\Omega^{-1}$ and regroup the terms:
$$
\omega=-\Sigma^{-1} (\mu-r) \frac{2J_W}{WJ_{WW}} -\frac{2}{WJ_{WW}}\Sigma^{-1}\Phi\frac{\delta J_w}{\delta x}
$$
You missed factor 2 somewhere.
REMARK. 
There is a certain confusion in your indexes too. If $x$ is a $k$ dimensional vector, why the sum in (*) over $n$? It should be over $k$ and then $\Phi$  is a $nxk$ matrix

Comment: You are right. I had a typo. In the textbook, there is no 1/2 in Equation (*). Thanks.